# my img only display a half. CSS issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a problem about CSS issue. My image only half displays when I try to add new image.

```css
ul.social li{
 display: inline-block; 
}
ul.social li  i{
 background: url(../images/img-sprite.png)no-repeat -4px -36px ;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
ul.social li  i.twitter{
 background-position:  -64px -36px;
}
ul.social li i.google{
 background-position: -122px -35px;
}
ul.social li i.ig{
 background-position: -200px -35px;
}
ul.social li  i:hover{
 background-position:  -4px -93px;
}
ul.social li  i.twitter:hover{
 background-position:  -64px -94px;
}
ul.social li i.google:hover{
 background-position: -122px -92px;
}
ul.social li i.ig:hover{
 background-position: -200px -92px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 footer-top">
     <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="#"><i> </i></a></li>      
      <li><a href="#"><i class="twitter"> </i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="google"> </i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="ig"> </i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

And Here is the result : 
[image: the instagram logo only display a half]

can anybody help me here to solve my problem?

Comment: can you make a js fiddle?  I think it might have something to do with `margin: 0 5px 0 0;` but I'm not sure. The code snipped doesn't run correctly.

Comment: it can also just be that the position of the icon in the sprite sheet is not correct. But to check that we would need the actual sprite image. VXp why are you not using font-icons (or svg) for this?

Comment: Can you use an absolute `url` for the background, to try to make the snippet working?

Comment: @cloned Probably because I'm not the OP, what do you think?

Comment: We will indeed need the original sprite-sheet to check what's wrong. You can upload it to stackexchange's imgur just like you did for the repro-screenshot. At first glance, I would say that you background-position-x:-200px doesn't match the usual 58px your other icons have, should be -180px, but that icon also seems bigger, in which case, you'd probably be better fix your spritesheet.

Comment: @kafi i think you need to space your icons a bit. Try to calculate the distance between your icons.

Comment: use generator and you will get the exact values : https://www.toptal.com/developers/css/sprite-generator

Comment: Also, your new instagram icon circle is pretty crispy when put next to the others. Look at all of that aliasing!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how sprite.png is laid out, but you probably just need to change:

```
ul.social li i.ig{
    background-position: -200px -35px;
}
```

to

```
ul.social li i.ig{
    background-position: -170px -35px;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that number?

Comment: estimated based on the width of the icons. I assume there will be some tuning to get it right.